# SQL Server expression substitution in SELECT statements as column names

Tags: sql-server

How do I evaluate a character expression to resolve to a valid column name in a SELECT statement that would return column row values? Eg valid column name = Customer_1 == 'Customer_'+'1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL. An example

```
DECLARE @DynSQL nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @Suffix int = 1

SET @DynSQL = N'SELECT Customer_' + CAST(@Suffix as nvarchar(10)) + 
              N' FROM YourTable WHERE foo = @foo'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynSQL, N'@foo int', @foo=1
```

As always with dynamic SQL you need to consider SQL injection if any of the inputs to the process will be user supplied.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Is using sp_executesql the only way to do this?

Comment: @david - Yes. `sp_executesql` or `Exec`. The former is preferred though as it allows you to parametrise the query.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I evaluate a character expression to resolve to a valid column name in a SELECT statement that would return column row values? Eg valid column name = Customer_1 == 'Customer_'+'1'

You're probably doing something wrong if you need to do this, but if you have to: build the column names as rows and then pivot.

Comment: Not good practice; agreed. Need to re-org a read-in XLS to a table.  More data manip tool than 'data management'  Save someone at least 2 hours by hand.

Comment: This solution will not work in SQL Server. The only way is dynamic SQL.